# Alter type in PostgreSQL 8.3.8

Tags: postgresql, types

There's a data type I'm using that contains a character(6) field.  I want to change it to a varchar(7) field.  Unfortunately, I'm on a server using PostgreSQL 8.3.8, and ALTER TYPE didn't have much functionality back then.  It's also the case that this column is being used by several functions, so it won't let me remove the attribute and put a new one in with the right parameters.

Here's what I mean:

```
mydb=# \d t_emp_start_stop_2
Composite type "public.t_emp_start_stop_2"
    Column    |     Type
--------------+--------------
 employee_id  | character(6)
 normal_start | integer
 normal_stop  | integer
 normal_lunch | integer
```

I want to replace employee_id with a varchar(7) field.  Is there a way to do this cleanly?

Comment: 8.3x is end of life ... so consider an update (independent from your problem ...)

Answer (score 0):

If you can live with changing the type name, and are in a position to change the type on all related functions, then you can probably get away with moving to a new type.

```sql
-- create a new type
CREATE TYPE public.t_emp_start_stop_2_new AS (
    employee_id VARCHAR(7),
    normal_start INTEGER,
    normal_stop INTEGER,
    normal_lunch INTEGER
);

-- create a function that takes the old type and outputs the new type
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION t_emp_start_stop_2_new_converter(value1 t_emp_start_stop_2)
RETURNS t_emp_start_stop_2_new AS $$
DECLARE
    newtype t_emp_start_stop_2_new;
BEGIN
    newtype.employee_id = value1.employee_id;
    newtype.normal_start = value1.normal_start;
    newtype.normal_stop = value1.normal_stop;
    newtype.normal_lunch = value1.normal_lunch;
    return newtype;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE STRICT;

-- create a cast from the old to new type
CREATE CAST (t_emp_start_stop_2 AS t_emp_start_stop_2_new)
WITH FUNCTION t_emp_start_stop_2_new_converter(t_emp_start_stop_2);

-- update table to use new type
ALTER TABLE abc
ALTER xyz TYPE t_emp_start_stop_2_new
USING xyz::t_emp_start_stop_2_new;

-- UPDATE ALL EXISTING FUNCTIONS TO USE NEW TYPE HERE

-- drop old cast, function and type
DROP CAST (t_emp_start_stop_2 AS t_emp_start_stop_2_new);
DROP FUNCTION t_emp_start_stop_2_new_converter(t_emp_start_stop_2);
DROP TYPE t_emp_start_stop_2;
```